# java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '?'

Tags: java, regex, groovy

I have a regEx `def regex = "^Line[\\s]+(?:(\\d+)\\s)?\\s*:\\s+(\\d+)?.+";` which matches below strings

```
Line 1 : testMessage1
Line : 2 testMessage2
```

Now am trying to make regex to make `:` as optional so that it can match strings like

```
Line 3 testMessage3
```

I've tried changing my regEx as `^Line[\s]+(?:?(\d+)\s)?\s*:?\s+(\d+)?.+`

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '?' near index 13 
^Line[\s]+(?:?(\d+)\s)?\s*:?\s+(\d+)?.+
```

can someone please help me fixing the regEx?

Comment: You cannot make the `(?:` optional, it is part of a non-capturing group. Remove the `?` after it.

Comment: Well, you may try [`^Line(?:(?:\s*:)?\s*(\d+))?.+`](https://regex101.com/r/NAWWto/3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your regex:

```
^Line[\s]+(?:?(\d+)\s)?\s*:?\s+(\d+)?.+
             ^----- Here, remove this '?'
```

On the other hand, if you want to have the colon as optional, you have to fix the `\s`:

```
Line\s+(?:(\d+)\s*)?\s*:?\s+(\d+)?.+
                 ^---- Here
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/fI08WG/1)**

In addition, I cleaned up a little your regex that you might find useful:

```
Line\s+(\d)?\s*:?\s*(\d)?.*
```

Comment: @FedericoPiazza that fixes the syntax error, but not matches the required string `Line 3 testMessage3`, can you please me fixing it to match the required string

Answer (score 1):

```
^Line[\s]+(?:?(\d+)\s)?\s*:?\s+(\d+)?.+
             ^----- This is a mistake
```

The `?` there is a mistake, because the `:` is part of a `(?:...)` grouping expression, not a literal `:` character.

Let's try to rework your regex based on your requirements:

- Start with `Line`
- Followed by at least 1 space
- Followed by either of:

  - Digits and one or more space and `:`
  - `:` and one or more space and digits
  - Digits
- Followed by space
- Followed by anything

This pattern matches your 3 examples:

```
"^Line\\s+(\\d+\\s+:|:\\s+\\d+|\\d+) .*"
```